# A scanario in Graph database to extract data

Tags: gremlin, titan

I have following scanerio:

```
    +--belongsToL1(catg:c1)--->P1[(name:This is p1)]--belongsToL2--\
    +--belongsToL1(catg:c2)--->P1[(name:This is p1)]--belongsToL2-->TOP-A(name:this is topA)
    +--belongsToL1(catg:c3)--->P1[(name:This is p1)]--belongsToL2--/
Page+
    +--belongsToL1(catg:cc1)--->P1[(name:This is p11)]--belongsToL2--\
    +--belongsToL1(catg:cc2)--->P1[(name:This is p11)]--belongsToL2-->TOP-B(name:this is topB)
    +--belongsToL1(catg:cc3)--->P1[(name:This is p11)]--belongsToL2--/
```

Now I want these data:

`This is TopA :: This is p1 :: c1, c2, c3`

`This is TopB :: This is p11 :: cc1, cc2, cc3`

How can I do that ?

Comment: Can a "TOP" have multiple "P" vertices?

Comment: yes "TOP" vertices could be connected with multiple "P" vertices coming inside

Answer (score 0):

You have a Tree structure here, so why no use the [tree() step](http://gremlindocs.com/#side-effect/tree).  Something like:

```
g.v('TOP-A','TOP-B').in('belongsToL2').in('belongsToL1').tree().cap()
```

Note that `tree` is a side-effect step so to get that tree variable out of there you need to call `cap` to pop it out.  You could also pass a `Tree` instance to `tree` step and it would write the side effect to that as shown in the GremlinDocs link I provided.